# extracting and print particular pattern strings from a directory files and it's subdirectory files using awk or gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

I wants to print words [ if a pattern like  value="any string"  but not value="#{any string}" ]  in all files in a directory and their sub directory.

```
dir1
     file1
           ( content like ..... value="GOD Grace" .....
                ....................................value="#{blog}"......
                ... value="Greek" ...)
     file2
           ( content like ..... value="Sounder rajan" .....
             ....................................value="#{feek}".....
             ....................................value="patient"....)


             subdir1
                       file3
                            ( content like ..... value="Guice" .....
                            ....................................value="#{slog}"......
                            ... value="guide" ...)
```

i wants the out put like

```
         filename  filewordno   wordsExtract   uniqno
         file1        1                GOD Grace      1
         file1        2                Greek              2
         file2        1                Sounder rajan   3
         file2        2                patient             4
         file3        1                Guice              5
         file3        2                guide               6
```

My Try:

```
no=0;

for SourceFile in *.xhtml
do
    pagename=$(basename $filename .xhtml)
    cat $SourceFile | gawk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \"]"}
     wno=0;
/value=/ && !/value=\"#/ && !/pages/ && !/value=\"[0-9]\"/  {
for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {

    if (( !/#/ && /value=/ ) && $i == "value=" && $(i+1)!=""  && $(i+1)!=":"  && $(i+1)!="*" ){
        print SourceFile,++wno,$(i+1),++no;

    }

}
 }'
done >>  path/Outputfilename
```

my otput

```
filename  filewordno   wordsExtract   uniqno
             -        1                Grace              1
             -        1                Greek              2
             -        1                Sounder           1
             -        1                patient             2
```

My 3 problems

1. Words shold not split on space i want the strings with spaces like 'GOD Grace' not like Grace.`enter code here
2. I want subdirectory files also .But by my script, i  can only print the main directory files only
3. and i want unique s.nofor all words.

I study and work for this for last 1 week .If u have time,your help is more presious for me.

thanks

Comment: I tried fixing your formatting but it still doesn't make sense so please take a look and correct it so it does accurately reflect your input and tell us if your input is stored in a file or if you're describing a directory hierarchy on your machine. Provide input and output such that when we run your script against the input, it produces the output you provide.

Answer (score 0):

I guess simple grep command inside a loop can do what you are looking for, If you are okay to accept solution without awk parsing then please check the below script and it's output, I used the same content you used in your question.

Script (**extract_values.sh**)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loop to parse all files recursively in current directory
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.xhtml" -print`
do
  v_currdir=`pwd`              # store the current working directory in a variable
  v_file_path=`dirname $file`  # extract file path seperately
  v_file_name=`basename $file` # extract file name seperately
  cd $v_file_path              # change to that directory

  # command to extract the required data
  grep -o -H 'value=\".*\"' $v_file_name | grep -v 'value=\"#.*\"' | sed 's/value=//g' | grep -nv 'StringNotToBeFound'

  # Again change the directory to current working directory for next itreation
  cd $v_currdir
done
```

Sample Execution of the script

```
$ ls
dir1  extract_values.sh

$ find . -print
.
./dir1
./dir1/file1.xhtml
./dir1/file2.xhtml
./dir1/subdir1
./dir1/subdir1/file3.xhtml
./extract_values.sh

$ # this is the command using the above script to add header 
$ # And change the delimiter to tab from colon using tr command
$ (echo "UniqNO:FWordNo:FileName:WordsExtract"; extract_values.sh | nl -s: ) | tr ':' "\t"
UniqNO  FWordNo FileName        WordsExtract
     1  1       file1.xhtml     "GOD Grace"
     2  2       file1.xhtml     "Greek"
     3  1       file2.xhtml     "Sounder rajan"
     4  2       file2.xhtml     "patient"
     5  1       file3.xhtml     "Guice"
     6  2       file3.xhtml     "guide"
$
```

Comment: thanks a lot narendra iits works well.thanks.all so thanks for Ed Morton.